# Ambiguous reference to member 'append'

Tags: swift

I am beginner in Swift and learning swift from "The Swift Programming language(Swift 3 beta)". In this book, there is one example of creating generic function but I am getting the above mentioned error.

```
func makeArray<Item>(repeating item: Item, numberOfTimes: Int)->[Item]
{
    var result = [Item]()

    for _ in 0..<numberOfTimes {

        return.append(item)//Error here.

    }

    return result
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
return.append(item)
```

should be:

```
result.append(item)
```

You cannot append to return, it only returns the value.